# Tags "script" do HTML recebem "thread" exclusiva pra cada uma no navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, thread

Se separar processos JavaScript em *tags* `<SCRIPT>` valem a pena para o processamento individual de cada programação, ou o navegador junta tudo num processo único?

Alguém que entenda realmente de sistema operacional e *threads* geradas poderia me informar isso?

Vou ser mais claro. Imaginem o seguinte código:

```
<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
          operações gerais aqui de manipulação de DOM
   });
</script>
<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      uma chamada de player de um video
   });
</script>
```

Eu gostaria que a chamada de *player* de vídeo fosse executada independente de todas as operações da manipulação de DOM da *tag* anterior. Separando em duas *tags* `<SCRIPT>` isso vai acontecer?

Comment: Tanto quando sei JavaScript é _single threaded_, esses dois pedaços de código vão ser corridos sequencialmente e não paralelamente.

Comment: Valeu @Sergio . Não tinha conhecimento que era single e sequencial. Até imaginava ser sequencial, mas não tinha certeza. O mundo html hoje tá muito assincrono, vai saber... hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não. você não pode separar a execução em processos ou *threads* desta forma. Todo *engine* do JavaScript será executado em ambiente único.

Pode até existir algumas situações que o navegador possa fazer algumas operações, em geral coisas internas, em uma *thread* separada. Mas isto é um "problema" dele. Não conte com isto.

Para a programação do *script* você deve considerar que está rodando tudo em uma só *thread*, apesar de que nem sempre isso seja verdade especialmente se estiver usando APIs assíncronas, eventos e `setInterval` (fica a dica de como obter um resultado próximo do que você deseja).

Cada bloco `<script>` é executado sequencialmente e não paralelamente. Inclusive a ordem que cada bloco aparece na página influencia a execução. No máximo o que você pode conseguir é que um *script* vindo externamente por um `src` seja carregado em paralelo, mas sua execução será sequencial respeitando a ordem em que ele aparece na página.

Então a ordem de execução é garantida... até que você roda em um *browser* que não siga o padrão. Adivinha qual *browser* não dá esta garantia? É o mesmo de sempre que é diferente dos outros.

Parece que o HTML permite que isto seja especificado com `<script type="text/javascript" async src="script.js"></script>` mas não sei como está a implementação nos navegadores. Note que isto se refere apenas à carga do arquivo (possivelmente o *parse* e compilação/JIT também).

De qualquer forma isto é um detalhe de implementação do navegador e não algo especificado, algo que você pode considerar.

Se você quer execução simultânea precisa usar [WebWorkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker), se o navegador tiver este recursos disponível.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Gostei de conhecer o WebWorkers e valeu a dica do setInterval.